# Error: Cloud Functions for Firebase spawn EACCES (ghostscript)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, ghostscript

I tried using Firebase Cloud Functions to create a thumbnail of a PDF file.
After the call of gs I get the following error:

> 2018-06-12T11:29:08.685Z E makeThumbnail: Error: spawn EACCES
>
> at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>
> at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:328:11)
>
> at exports.spawn (child_process.js:370:9)
>
> at Object.exec (/user_code/node_modules/gs/index.js:86:28)
>
> at Promise (/user_code/index.js:95:12)
>
> at mkdirp.then.then (/user_code/index.js:86:12)
>
> 2018-06-12T11:29:08.698166767Z D makeThumbnail: Function execution took 780 ms, finished with status: 'error'

Is it necessary to use a component like ghostscript to use a plan other than Spark?

In addition, my code. Maybe I just do not see my problem in the code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp-promise');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const gs = require('gs');
const THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT = 200;
const THUMB_MAX_WIDTH = 200;
const THUMB_PREFIX = 'thumb_';
const gs_exec_path = path.join(__dirname, './lambda-ghostscript/bin/gs');

try{admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); } catch(e) {}

exports.makeThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {

  const filePath = object.name;
  const contentType = object.contentType; 
  const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${THUMB_PREFIX} ${fileName}`));
  const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
  const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
  const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);

  const tmp_dir = os.tmpdir();


  if (fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)) {
    console.log('Is thumbnail');
    return null;
  }


  const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
  const file = bucket.file(filePath);
  const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath);
  const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
  };

  return mkdirp(tmp_dir).then(() => {
     console.log("Dir Created");

    console.log(tempLocalFile);
    return file.download({destination: tempLocalFile});
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("File downloaded");
    if(!contentType.startsWith("image/")){

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const pg= 1;
      gs().batch().nopause()
        .option(`-dFirstPage=${pg}`)
        .option(`-dLastPage=${pg}`)
        .executablePath(gs_exec_path)
        .device('png16m')
        .output(tempLocalThumbFile+".png")
        .input(tempLocalFile)
        .exec(err => err ? reject(err) : resolve());
      });
    }
    else
    {
      var args = [ tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocalThumbFile ];
      return spawn('convert', args, {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']});
    }
  }).then(() => {

    return bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, { destination: thumbFilePath });
  }).then(() => {

    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);

    return result[0];
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of scratching my head and running same code over and over again pointlessly, I've finally found the problem!

The executable path that you've defined is not correct. It should be `'gs'`.

Here's a complete gs() call sample:

```
gs()
    .batch()
    .option('-dFirstPage=2')
    .option('-dLastPage=2')
    .nopause()
    .res(90)
    .executablePath('gs')
    .device('jpeg')
    .output(tempNewPath2)
    .input(tempFilePath)
    .exec((err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('gs executed w/o error');
        console.log('stdout', stdout);
        console.log('stderr', stderr);
        resolve();
      } else {
        console.log('gs error:', err);
        reject(err);
      }
    });
```

For more help, you can go through a sample repo that I created for this issue
https://github.com/krharsh17/ghostscript-firebase-sample